# Laravel5でデータベースセッションを使う

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel5でデータベースセッションを使いたいのですが
artisanコマンドを使ってsessionsテーブルを作成しました。

```
php artisan session:table
php artisan migrate
```

実行後、作られたテーブルの使い方がよく分かりません。
いつ、値がDBにセットされるのでしょうか？
自分で値を決めてセットしたりなどもできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 使い方というのはhttps://readouble.com/laravel/5.5/ja/session.html　こちらにあるようなSessionの使い方ですか？それともsessionテーブルを使いたいという話ですか？

Comment: sessionテーブルを使いたいです！